# For minimisation problems why do use the negative gradient to move towards a minimum?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, numerical-calculus

Why is the negative of the gradient used, instead of the actual gradient. Moreover, I am a bit confused on how the vector of the gradient points, like how do you determine in which way it points. Sorry if this seems vague, Im just really confused by the gradient of multidimensional minimisation problems.

Comment: It's quite simple, for a minimization problem we would like the function value to decrease, therefore we need to progress in the negative direction of the gradient. Also, it can be shown that the largest decease in the function value **per iteration** is attained when taking the negative of the gradient. Therefore this specific implementation is called "steepest descent". Note that while this choice of direction seems to make sense, it is a greedy type direction and other choices can have an overall better performance

Comment: But why do we say the negative of the gradient is the best? I understand that its best to move along the gradient to gain the maximum amount of change over an iteration globally, but why not move in the direction of the gradient